# Output of shell_exec forced to screen

Tags: php, apache, terminal

I am using shell_exec to run terminal commands through PHP script -

```
$output=shell_exec('find -L $APACHE_PREFIX \! -type l \! -type s -perm /g=w -ls');
```

but the problem is instead of sending the output to the variable, the output is directly printed on terminal screen.

Comment: Probably the output is from stderr. Add this to your command line : 2>&1 and maybe you'll get it

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to capture the buffer :

```
<?php
ob_start();
$output = shell_exec('find -L $APACHE_PREFIX ! -type l ! -type s -perm /g=w -ls 2>&1');
$output_captured = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Hello Loic, actually this shell_exec command gives thousands of lines of output and still I am facing the same problem. Output is simply flooding my terminal.

Comment: Edited, you won't have any output from now on.